# Java networking, cant figureout what's wrong with multithread server

Tags: java, multithreading

my name is Jędrzej and I am new here.  I was trying to write a simple chat in java. I am trying to make multithread server so multiple clients can connect to this server. My client works fine, but if I run two clients, they dont see each others responses. Code bellow:`

```
package serverthread;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerWIthThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
            while(true){
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Runnable r = new ThreadForServer(socket);
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();

            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}



  package serverthread;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ThreadForServer implements Runnable{

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    public ThreadForServer(Socket i){

        socket = i;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try{
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.flush();

            while(true){
                String message = (String) inputStream.readObject();
                outputStream.writeObject(message);
                outputStream.flush();
            }

        }catch(IOException e){

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've implemented this, you're reading a message from one client and then writing it back to the *same* client.

You'll need to revise your program so that you can write the message to the `Socket` of the other connected client.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but I'm still not sure what should I do ;( Could you write an example code?